# 1099-Misc Box 3 Other Income

Tags: united-states, ira, form-1099-misc

I am retired and receive a small amount from a family trust for which I am a trustee.

When I was working I had more than enough earned income to make the maximun IRA and Spousal IRA contributions each year.

Is the annual fee I receive from the family trust as 1099-Misc Box 3 Other Income considered earned income for purposes of contributing to an IRA?